# Monitoring the progress of FindRoot during evaluation

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to know whether there is a way to monitor the evaluation of the norm of the error of `FindRoot`. Sometimes the evaluation of of this for a large system can takes minutes, hours or days, and I would like to see which parameters (e.g., damping factor) can lead to improvement of  the performance of `FindRoot`.

e.g., Suppose I solve the complex system

```
FindRoot[Equations, Start];
```

I would like to get an update at every iteration about:
1) the iteration number
2) the norm of error of the function

Comment: Just in case you haven't seen this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationPlottingSearchData.html The package `UnconstrainedProblems` has a few interesting functions-

Comment: I was not aware of this! The plotting takes time to execute but would provide great intuition for test cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`EvaluationMonitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) to print progress. For example:

```
n = 0;
f[x_] := Cos[x];
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 8}, EvaluationMonitor :> (n++; Print[{n, f[x]^2}])]
```

Gives:

```
{1,0.0211703}
{2,1.09558*10^-6}
{3,1.46112*10^-19}
{4,9.3735*10^-32} 
{x -> 7.85398}
```

Comment: works great! Is there any way the stepsize could be influenced?

Comment: @Breugem What do you mean? Only to show the progress every 5 steps, say? or change the internal step size of `FindRoot`?

Comment: I was referring to the internal step size of Findroot

Comment: I don't think you can do that. At least, I don't know how to.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider replacing `EvaluationMonitor` by `StepMonitor`.

Comment: @Breugem `FindRoot` does not use fixed steps! Do you know the [`Newton method`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for finding roots? There the step-size depends on the gradient and the function-value. For other methods used by `FindRoot` the situation is equivalent. Therefore, you can not influence the step-size directly through an option.

Comment: @Breugem Here you get the stepsizes: `L = {}; f[x_] = Cos[x]; FindRoot[f[x], {x, 8}, EvaluationMonitor :> (AppendTo[L, x]; Print[Abs[f[x]]])]` and then 
`StepSizes = Differences[L]`

Comment: Suppose `f[x]` is expensive to evaluate, so I want to print it after each step without re-evaluating. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've tried `FindRoot[(val=f[x];val),...]... Print[n,val]`, but it seems to still re-evaluate `f[x]`.