# How to monitor the progress of LinearSolve?

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra, monitoring, internals

I am trying to do something like

```
d = RandomReal[{0, 50}, 3];
U = ResourceFunction["RandomMatrix"]["Orthogonal", Real, 3];
m = Transpose[U] . DiagonalMatrix[d] . U;
b = {6, 4, 5};
LinearSolve[N@m, N@b, 
 Method -> {"Krylov", Method -> "ConjugateGradient"}]
```

and want to monitor the decline of residue in the solving process.
It seems that [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) do not have the [`StepMonitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StepMonitor.html) and [`EvaluationMonitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html) options,
which are only [available for iterative built-in functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalOperationsOnFunctions.html.en?source=footer#:%7E:text=But%20particularly%20for%20numerical%20functions%20that%20use%20iterative%20algorithms).

I'm guessing blindly that, `LinearSolve` is not eligible for these options because even when [an iterative method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html.en#:%7E:text=For%20sparse%20arrays,ARPACK%20Arnoldi%20methods.) is specified, the iterating procedure is handled by low-level linalg libraries, rather than within the Wolfram language abstraction. If this is the case, it seems also to rule out the possibility of achieving this with [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

Is there some other way I have not think of that may do the trick?

Related posts:

1. [Monitoring the execution of Solve - @StarBucK](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149527/monitoring-the-execution-of-solve)
2. [What does LinearSolve Preconditioner do? - Answer by @Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172338/72025)

---

Indirect workaround: Since this is not a real world problem,
one can always use CG `FindMinimum` on
the corresponding variational minimization problem,
and `StepMonitor` the process.
I however still appreciate further insights on the internals of `LinearSolve`.
From the second linked post I understand that there is internally the function `` SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve ``; is it possible to probe its implementation?

Comment: Comment not directly related to your question: Instead of the resource function, one can use `U = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[3]]`.

Comment: @user293787 Thanks! I intend to investigate the sampling measure of the resource function too

Comment: **I'm guessing blindly that, LinearSolve is not eligible for these options** That is correct.   **There is no direct way to monitor exact linear algebra computations.** reference  
Daniel Lichtblau in comment to the first link.

Comment: I seem to have doomed myself with ever-prolonging time working on this, got to stop and take a note. How does built-in functions handle sub-options exactly? `LinearSolve[m, b, Method -> {"Krylov", <suboptions>}]` should take string option keys, but it also accepts symbol keys; is this intended? How can I do this in my custom functions?

Answer (score 7):

I think I got it. MSE rules and this should be obvious had I been competent.
This is what @unlikely did in his [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82645/72025)

```
Reap@LinearSolve[m, b, Method -> {"Krylov", 
    "ResidualNormFunction" -> ((Sow[#, "residue_vector"]; Sow[Norm[#, 2]]) &)
  }
]
```

This should intuitively suffice the purpose in question, however does not.

---

I finished my mock-up that I think is mathematically equivalent to @user293787 's

```
ClearAll[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve]
Module[{symbol = Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve, $symbol = 
    SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve},
  ((MessageName[Evaluate@symbol, #] = 
       MessageName[Evaluate@$symbol, #]) &) /@ ToExpression[
     FindList[
      FileNameJoin[{System`Private`$MessagesDir, $Language, 
        "Messages.m"}], ToString[$symbol]]
     , StandardForm, HoldForm][[All, 1, 1, -1]]
  ];
Options[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve] ^= 
  Options[SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve];
SyntaxInformation[
   Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve] ^= {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, 
     OptionsPattern[]}, 
   "OptionNames" -> 
    Union[First /@ Options[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve], 
     First /@ Options[SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve]]};
Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve[m_, b_, 
  opt : OptionsPattern[SparseArray`KrylovLinearSolve]] := 
 Module[{dim = Dimensions[m][[1]], 
    maxiter = OptionValue[MaxIterations], tol = OptionValue[Tolerance],
    x0 = OptionValue["StartingVector"], 
    resnorm = OptionValue["ResidualNormFunction"] /. Automatic -> Norm,
    CGfunc},
   
   CGfunc = 
    Function[{n, A, \[FormalB], \[FormalCapitalN], \[Epsilon], x0}, 
     Module[{x = x0, r = \[FormalB] - A . x0, 
       p = \[FormalB] - A . x0, \[Alpha], \[Beta]},
      Do[If[resnorm[r] < \[Epsilon], Break[]]; 
       If[p . A . p == 0, 
        Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::krystg]; Break[]];
       \[Alpha] = Norm[r]^2/p . A . p; 
       x += \[Alpha] p; \[Beta] = Norm[r - A . (\[Alpha] p)]^2/
        Norm[r]^2; r -= A . (\[Alpha] p); p = \[Beta] p + r,
       \[FormalCapitalN]]; 
      If[resnorm[r] > \[Epsilon], 
       Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::krymit, \
\[FormalCapitalN]]]; x
      ]];
   If[Precision[{m, b}] == \[Infinity], 
    Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::kryinfp]];
   (*
   If[Head[m]==SparseArray\[And]m["Background"]!=0,Message[
   Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::kryinz,"m"]];
   If[Head[b]==SparseArray\[And]b["Background"]!=0,Message[
   Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::kryinz,"b"]];
   *)
   Switch[OptionValue[Method],
    Automatic | "ConjugateGradient", 
    CGfunc[dim, m, b, maxiter /. Automatic -> n, 
     tol /. Automatic -> 10^-12, 
     x0 /. Automatic -> ConstantArray[0, dim]]
    ]
   ] /; And[CheckArguments[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve[m, b, opt], 2],
   (If[MatrixQ[m], True, 
     Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::matrix, m, 1];
     If[MatrixQ[Evaluate@m], True, 
      Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::krynfa, m, 1]]; False]),
   (VectorQ[b] \[Or] 
     If[MatrixQ[b], True, 
      Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::matrix, b, 2]; False]),
   ((OptionValue[MaxIterations] == Automatic) \[Or] 
     If[IntegerQ@OptionValue[MaxIterations], True, 
      Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::kryit, 
       OptionValue[MaxIterations]]; False]),
   ((OptionValue["StartingVector"] == Automatic) \[Or] 
     If[VectorQ[OptionValue["StartingVector"], NumberQ], True, 
      Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::kryivec]; False]),
   Switch[OptionValue[Method],
    Automatic | "ConjugateGradient", True,
    "SteepestDescent" | "Lanczos" | "Arnoldi" | "MinRES" | "GMRES" | 
     "CGR" | "CGNR" | "CGLE" | "QMR" | "BiCG" | "BiCGStab", 
    Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::krynimp]; False,
    _, Message[Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve::kryme, 
     OptionValue["Method"]]; False
    ]
   ]
```

On the cases from [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/276076/72025),

```
SeedRandom[1];
dim = 2000;
U = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[dim]];
A = Transpose[U] . DiagonalMatrix[RandomReal[{1/100, 1}, dim]] . U;
b = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dim];
{sol, reap} = 
  LinearSolve[A, b, 
    Method -> {"Krylov", Method -> "ConjugateGradient", 
      "ResidualNormFunction" -> ((Sow[Norm[#]]) &)}] // Reap;
{mysol, myreap} = 
 Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve[A, b, Method -> "ConjugateGradient", 
   "ResidualNormFunction" -> ((Sow[Norm[#]]) &)] // 
  Reap; 
ListLinePlot[{reap[[1]], myreap[[1]]}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
{sol, reap} = 
  LinearSolve[N@A, N@b, 
    Method -> {"Krylov", Method -> "ConjugateGradient", 
      "ResidualNormFunction" -> ((Sow[Norm[#]]) &)}] // Reap;
{mysol, myreap} = 
 Gravifer`myKrylovLinearSolve[N@A, N@b, Method -> "ConjugateGradient",
    "ResidualNormFunction" -> ((Sow[Norm[#]]) &)] // 
  Reap; 
ListLinePlot[{reap[[1]], myreap[[1]]}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

The results are

[image: ListLinePlot[{reap[[1]], myreap[[1]]}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]]

So maybe as @unlikely indeed suggested in his post, `OptionValue["ResidualNormFunction"]` is not called once per iteration for the built-in function.

Comment: Good idea, but did you try it? If I try this using `A` and `b` in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/276076/85954), then the "ResidualNormFunction" seems to be evaluated only three times, and the only residue norms that one obtains are `{44.7214,26.0726,1.43976*10^-8}`. I do not think it only uses three steps? I use V12.3.

Comment: @user293787 I did some small scale tests, and I really assumed tha was the case. I'm a little confused right now... darn it

Answer (score 5):

Not directly an answer, but here is an implementation of conjugate gradient for a real, symmetric and positive definite matrix $A$. It `Sow`s the norm of the residual at each step. This implementation uses more matrix-vector multiplications than necessary:

```
linearSolveConjugateGradient[A_,b_,tol_:10^(-10)] := Module[{p,x,r},
    p = {};
    x = 0.*b;
    Do[
       r = A.x-b;
       If[Sow[Norm[r]]<tol,Break[]];
       p = {r,First[p,Nothing]} // Developer`ToPackedArray;
       p[[1]] = LeastSquares[p.A.Transpose[p],-p.r].p;
       x += p[[1]];
    ,{Infinity}];
    x
];
```

**Example.** Create a large (whatever that means) matrix $A$ with condition number about 100:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dim = 2000;
U = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[dim]];
A = Transpose[U].DiagonalMatrix[RandomReal[{1/100,1},dim]].U;
b = RandomReal[{-1,1},dim];
```

Monitor progress:

```
ListLogPlot[Last[Reap[linearSolveConjugateGradient[A,b]]],
            AxesLabel->{"step","Norm[residual]"}]
```

[image]

In this particular example, it is faster than the built-in conjugate gradient solver:

```
Norm[A.linearSolveConjugateGradient[A,b]-b] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.606085, 8.21629*10^-11} *)

Norm[A.LinearSolve[A,b,Method->{"Krylov",Method->"ConjugateGradient"}]-b] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {11.5928, 2.43374*10^-10} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I do have a toy CG by myself, but I indeed forgot to use AbsoluteTiming to benchmark it.